# Change the number for outgoing call, add prefix

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

According to this blogpost on android developers blog it should be doable to change an outgoing call number:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html

The problem is that it doesn't work for me, my code:

```
String action = intent.getAction();
if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(action)) {
    // Try to read the phone number from previous receivers.
    String phonenumber = getResultData();

    if (phonenumber == null) {
        // We could not find any previous data. Use the original
        // phone
        // number in this case.
        phonenumber = intent
                .getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }

        String reformatedNumber = reformatNumber(phonenumber);
    setResultData(reformatedNumber);                                
}
```

Even though I reformat the number the phone number i dialed is the one being called up.

Any insight?

I have these permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
```

The weird thig is that when I call I number that is not stored in the phone book I have a service that tries to figure out who I'm calling and I have to press a "Call" button on a dialog to complete the call. Then my code works, but when I call someone from the phonebook or if i disable the look-up service it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the blogpost you mention:

> We have actually observed phones with
>   a priority 0 receiver for the
>   NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent installed out
>   of the box (this will be the last one
>   that is called after all others) that
>   completely ignores previous result
>   data which means that, in effect, they
>   disable any useful processing of
>   ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL (other than
>   canceling the call, which would still
>   work). The only workaround for this is
>   to also run your receiver at priority
>   0, which works due to particularities
>   of running 2 receivers at the same
>   priority but, by doing that, you break
>   one of the few explicit rules for
>   processing outgoing calls:
>
> “For consistency, any receiver whose
>   purpose is to prohibit phone calls
>   should have a priority of 0, to ensure
>   it will see the final phone number to
>   be dialed. Any receiver whose purpose
>   is to rewrite phone numbers to be
>   called should have a positive
>   priority. Negative priorities are
>   reserved for the system for this
>   broadcast; using them may cause
>   problems.”

Is it possible that you are running into the fact that on a handset you're code is being ignored by an intent installed by the provider at priority 0? You can test this by setting your priority to 0 as well.

Comment: I have tried this without any effect:  <intent-filter android:priority="0">
                <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: The weird thig is that when I call I number that is not stored in the phone book I have a service that tries to figure out who I'm calling and I have to press a "Call" button on a dialog to complete the call. Then my code works, but when I call someone from the phonebook or if i disable the look-up service it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a problem of order: the system receives ordered broadcast before your code, so changes make no effect.

Try changing [`android:priority`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority) attribute for the `<intent-filter>` element in the manifest to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: You think I should increase the priority?

Comment: Yes, the javadoc states that higher number means higher priority: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Yes, but doesn't higher priority translate to execute first? Or does it translate to ignore any conflicts? As mentioned above, 0 means execute last (I believe I will admit I'm here to learn so I could be wrong but that's how I'm understanding it.) So in this case the above answer is stating changing the priority to a higher number will not solve the problem and it will cause it to run first, and then be overridden by the priority 0 process running after. At least that's how I read "they disable any useful processing of ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL". Unless of course you say the above is wrong?